# When importing a character to Unity, textures and meshes don't appear

Tags: unity, textures, blender, models, 3d-meshes

I'm relatively new to Unity, and I'm left with doing this as my last step towards my task - importing my animated character to a game engine and program the movements.

The problems that I have noticed are the missing textures and meshes, you can see in the first picture how it should look like in Blender, and what results I get in Unity:
[image]

[image]

The apple here doesn't have any holes, I think only one material got imported, and it doesn't look right. Textures are missing, the leaf near the stem is completely filled with gray texture. At least the animations work perfectly...

Download link to my .blend file - https://pasteall.org/blend/6c14ec0d9446404b81251585f83f3551

Answer (score 1):

If you colored it with texture painting you need to import the texture to unity and if it still uncolorized you need to drag the texture to objects material.